# Problem solving super heterodyne receiver question

Tags: modulation, frequency-modulation, amplitude-modulation, demodulation

I have two problems which i am trying to solve but i am stuck on the half way.

I have the following first question, which i am trying to solve

[image]

I have solved the problem as following,

```
         required peak frequency = 75KHz/5 = 15KHz
         Center frequency (fc) = 104MHz/5 = 20.8MHz
         Local oscillator frequenct (Fo) = 12Mhz +20.8MHz = 32.8MHz
```

I am stuck with the Bandwidth, I know,

```
   BT= 2(beta + 1)fm
```

how do I calculate the **fm** and **beta** in order to calculate bandwidth?

**The another question is with the double stage heterodyne receiver.**

So far in this I have calculated the oscillator frequency which are as following,

```
fo1= (27.4 + 10.7)MHz = 38.1 MHz
fo2 = (10.7 + 0.455)MHz = 11.15 MHz
```

[image]

What does the **maximum bandwidth of the input filter** and the **minimum bandwidth** of the **first and second intermediate frequency** mean? does this has some thing with the **image frequency**?

Comment: In that last paragraph, one misunderstood assignment detail springs out at me - you're being asked to calculate the minimum bandwidth for the first and second intermediate frequency (IF) FILTERS, not of the FREQUENCIES.

Answer (score 1):

For an FM signal, bandwidth is given by, \$BW =2(\beta +1)f_m\$. Where, \$\beta = \dfrac{\Delta f}{f_m}\$, \$f_m\$ is the maximum frequency component in the modulating signal (15kHz) and \$\Delta f\$ is the frequency deviation (15kHz).

---

The input filter is a *bandpass preselection filter* used ahead of the mixer to suppress the image signal. The image frequency will be \$f_{LO}\pm f_{IF}\$ (signal frequency \$f_{LO}\mp f_{IF}\$), so I think the maximum allowable bandwidth for the mixer should be less than \$2f_{IF}\$.

The second intermediate filter is a *channel selection filter*, a narrowband filter with high Q value for channel selection. Hence it should have at least the bandwidth of the signal (\$2\times 15kHz\$ in your case).

The first intermediate filter need not be a having same bandwidth as the first one, but it should also have a minimum bandwidth as that of the first one.